# I am using 2 loops, 1 for input and 1 for td. Can we achieve the same functionality with 1 loop in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```js
$("#bodyTargets tr").filter(function(index) {
  const firstTdText = Number($(this).find("td:first").text()) || 0;
  return !(firstTdText >= (Number($txtStartMonth.val()) || 0) && firstTdText <= (Number($txtEndMonth.val()) || 0));
}).each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  });
  $(this).find("td").each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-borderless table-sm">
  <thead id="headTargets">
    <tr>
      <th width="80px">Period</th>
      <th width="150px">Month</th>
      <th width="80px">Status</th>
      <th width="100px">Actual Value</th>
      <th width="100px">Initial Target</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bodyTargets">
    <tr id="trDataPoint_23139687" data-recordid="23139687">
      <td id="tdProjectMonth_23139687">15</td>
      <td id="tdCalendarMonth_23139687">2024 - March</td>
      <td id="tdStatusL3_23139687">Pending</td>
      <td width="100px"><input class="form-control target-form" data-recordid="23139687" data-oldvalue="" id="txtActualValue_23139687" data-prevrecordid="" value=""></td>
      <td width="100px"><input class="form-control target-form" data-recordid="23139687" data-oldvalue="" id="txtInitialTarget_23139687" data-prevrecordid="" value=""></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trDataPoint_23139688" data-recordid="23139688">
      <td id="tdProjectMonth_23139688">16</td>
      <td id="tdCalendarMonth_23139688">2024 - April</td>
      <td id="tdStatusL3_23139688">Pending</td>
      <td width="100px"><input class="form-control target-form" data-recordid="23139688" data-oldvalue="" id="txtActualValue_23139688" data-prevrecordid="txtActualValue_23139687" value=""></td>
      <td width="100px"><input class="form-control target-form" data-recordid="23139688" data-oldvalue="" id="txtInitialTarget_23139688" data-prevrecordid="txtInitialTarget_23139687" value=""></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(this).find("input,td")`

Comment: What do you mean with "using 2 loops"? There are 3 `each` calls here.

Comment: I mean loops for td and input.

Comment: What is the HTML? Multiple inputs per td? Td without inputs? ... BTW you can use CSS to set those colors without any JavaScript.

Comment: Added the HTML as well in the post.

Comment: Please don't ask questions with code only. Answer clarifying questions posed in comments by [edit]ing your question and answering them with text.

Comment: There's no need for *either* .each in your code:  use the power of [tag:jquery] - `$(this).find("input").prop("disabled", true); $(this).find("input,td").css("color", "red");`

Comment: I'll also suggest that instead of .css("color"... you use `.addClass` , eg `$(this).addClass("error-row")` then set css accordingly:  `tr.error-row .td, tr.error-row input { color: red }`

Comment: You can then remove the *outer* loop as well: `$("#bodyTargets tr").filter(function(index) { ... }).addClass("error-row");`  (you can also "disable" inputs with css, pointer-events/style/etc) if not, just add the `.find("input")` change to the end of the above `addClass`

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Sure I will do it and txs fr editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to get both `input` and `td` and then in one `each` loop do what you need.

```
$("#bodyTargets tr").filter(function(index) {
  const firstTdText = Number($(this).find("td:first").text()) || 0;
  return !(firstTdText >= (Number($txtStartMonth.val()) || 0) && firstTdText <= (Number($txtEndMonth.val()) || 0));
}).find("input, td").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is("input")) {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  }
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```